# Ubuntu 20.04 -- Can't select Dark Theme option under Appearance panel

Tags: gnome, 20.04, themes

The problem is exactly same as I stated:
***Ubuntu 20.04 Dark Theme option doesn't get selected under Windows Color in Settings>Appearance***

Usually there is a highlight on the theme that's currently working, which is not here as in the picture.

[image]

I have also trying activating yaru-dark from gnome-tweaks appearance but no use.

Answer (score 1):

I think your Yaru themes are incomplete. I fixed mine with:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-session

sudo apt-get --reinstall install yaru-*
```

Comment: Thanks will try them out

Comment: Yes thanks, this works, I got my Appearance selection back.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just had to install `yaru-theme-gtk` which I accidentally uninstalled while installing dependencies for `Adobe acrobat`. I know it's kind of weird, but anyway after installing it again using the following command:

```
sudo apt install yaru-theme-gtk
```

I selected the dark theme from **Settings > Appearance** and it worked.